# how to dynamically append tr element with css to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looping through `$.each` in jquery and getting back data and appending that data to a table like this:

```
 $.each(segment, function (index, innerSegment) {
 var tr;
 tr = $('<tr/>');
 tr.append("<td>" + segment[i].Airline.AirlineName + "</td>");

 tr.append("<td>" + segment[i].ArrivalTime + "</td>");
 tr.append("<td>" + segment[i].Origin "</td>"); 

 tr.append("<td>" + segment[i].DepartureTime + "</td>");
 tr.append("<td>" + segment[i].Destination "</td>"); 

 tr.append("<td>" + segment[i].Duration + "</td>");
 tr.append("<td>" + segment[i].publishedFare "</td>");
 $('#tableId').append(tr);
}
```

Now, I am getting back proper data from `$.each` loop. But all the data is appending one after the another.

I want to append the data something like this in this jsfiddle.https://jsfiddle.net/1pbso9jt/

My table is like this:

```
<table id="tableId">
     <tr>   
       </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: can you share the segment data?

Comment: can try this `$.each(segment, function (index, innerSegment) {
 var tr;
 tr = $('<tr/>');
 tr = $('<tr/>');
 tr.append("<td rowspan="4">" + segment[i].Airline.AirlineName + "</td>");

 tr.append("<td>" + segment[i].ArrivalTime + "</td>");
 tr.append("<td>" + segment[i].Origin "</td>"); 

 tr.append("<td>" + segment[i].DepartureTime + "</td>");
 tr.append("<td>" + segment[i].Destination "</td>"); 

 tr.append("<td rowspan="4">" + segment[i].Duration + "</td>");
 tr.append("<td rowspan="4">" + segment[i].publishedFare "</td>");
 $('#tableId').append(tr);
}`

Comment: As far as i know `$('<tr/>')` is not a valid element selector try `$('tr')` if you really want to append to a table row. Though my suggestion is to append the whole block to your `#tableId`. E.g. `$('#tableId').append('<tr><td>' + segment[i].Airline.AirlineName + '</td></tr>');`. For a nicer looking code feel free to add a line break after or before the `+`, I prefer my code looking like it was pure html.

Comment: @guradio already tried not working

Comment: @duke can you share the segment value so i can create a demo ?

Comment: actually data is coming from rest api but i am sending u a demo fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L90ra64d/8/ have a look at it @guradio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this:

```js
var table = $('#tableId');
$.each(segment, function (index, innerSegment) {
  var rows = '<tr><td rowspan="4" width="25%">' + segment[i].Airline.AirlineName + "</td>";
  rows += '<td width="25%">' + segment[i].ArrivalTime + "</td>";
  rows += '<td rowspan="4" width="25%">&nbsp;</td>';
  rows += '<td rowspan="4" width="25%">' + segment[i].publishedFare + "</td></tr>";
  rows += "<tr><td>" + segment[i].Origin + "</td></tr>"; 
  rows += "<tr><td>" + segment[i].DepartureTime + "</td></tr>";
  rows += "<tr><td>" + segment[i].Destination + "</td></tr>"; 

  table.append(rows);
});
```

[Example fiddle with the each commented out](https://jsfiddle.net/1pbso9jt/2/)

[Updated fiddle with your data](https://jsfiddle.net/L90ra64d/10)

Comment: let me try it btw the demo fiddle with data is something like this https://jsfiddle.net/L90ra64d/8/ @Pete

Comment: Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L90ra64d/9/ you are unable to keep your thead though as you have changed the column structure (so it wouldn't make any sense anyway).  If you want to keep your headers, it would have to be something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/L90ra64d/10/

Comment: i dont want header it was just for reference initially @Pete if no header no prob at all

Comment: working fine can u tell me all the rows are sticking to each other if it is possible to have 5 px distance between each row @Pete

Comment: You can't really style table-rows, you would either have to add padding to the destination airport column: https://jsfiddle.net/L90ra64d/11/ or add a spacer row: https://jsfiddle.net/L90ra64d/12/

Answer (score 0):

You should combine your jsfiddle with the loop, like this:

```
$.each(segment, function (index, innerSegment) {
  var output;
  output = $('<table border="1"style="width:100%"><tr>');
  output.append("<td rowspan="4"style="width:25%">" + segment[i].Airline.AirlineName + "</td>");
  output.append("<td height="58">" + segment[i].ArrivalTime + "</td>");
  ...
  etcetera
  ...
  $('#tableId').append(output);
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L90ra64d/8/ this is the demo fiddle have a look at it @JoostS

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
$.each(segment, function (index, innerSegment) {
 var tr;
 tr = "<tr/>";
 tr+= "<td>" + segment[i].Airline.AirlineName + "</td>";

 tr+= "<td>" + segment[i].ArrivalTime + "</td>";
 tr+= "<td>" + segment[i].Origin "</td>";

 tr+= "<td>" + segment[i].DepartureTime + "</td>";
 tr+= "<td>" + segment[i].Destination "</td>"; 

 tr += "<td>" + segment[i].Duration + "</td>";
 tr += "<td>" + segment[i].publishedFare "</td>";
 $('#tableId').append(tr);
}
```